# I can't get this code to run properly. Display prime numbers from 1 to 100

Tags: c

**Program:**
I have to  make a program that displays all prime numbers between 1 to 100.

**History:**
*I have made a program that asks the user for a number, tells him whether or not it's a prime number, If it's not, the program displays its factors.*

**Confusion:**
But I cannot understand why this program (display prime no. from 1 to 100) wont run properly.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
//pre-processor directives
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//global variables/declarations
int factors=0;
int checkifprime(int num);

//main function - start
int main()
{
    //declaring loop variable
    int c;
    for (c=1;c<=100;c++)
    {
        if (c==1 ||c==2)
        {
            printf("\n%d is a prime number",c);
        }
        else
        {
            factors = 0;
            printf("error ");
            checkifprime(c);
            printf("error ");
            if (factors=0)
            {
                printf("\n%d is a prime number",&c);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("\n%d is NOT a prime number",&c);
            }
        }
    }

}

int checkifprime(int num)
{
    int i;
    if (num>0 && num<2147483640)
    {
        i = num-1;

        for (i;i>1;i--)
        {
            if (num%i==0)
            {
                factors=factors+1;

                printf(" %d",i);
            }
        }
    }

    //program finished
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Deciding what language it's written in would be a good start.

Comment: _"I cannot understand"_ is not a problem description.

Comment: is `1` a prime number?

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal I guess not.

Comment: Compile with `-Wall` and fix *all* of the warnings.  (Also, it's best to end each `printf` with a `\n`, unless you're deliberately stitching lines together with multiple `printfs`.)

Comment: It's executing all the statements at least once but, not more than that.@RobertColumbia

Comment: One reason it may not "run properly", is because `int checkifprime(int num)` only ever returns `0`.

Comment: What is? @LightnessRacesinOrbit

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh yeahh. I'll fix that and try.

Comment: @OmarQazi: What is what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had one small, but significant typo in it. If you would have switched on all warnings you would have caught it, so for the next time: switch on all warnings you compiler offers. After a bit of additional clean-up to get rid of the Windows-only stuff:

```
//pre-processor directives
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//global variables/declarations
int factors = 0;
int checkifprime(int num);

//main function - start
int main()
{
//declaring loop variable
  int c;
  puts("1 is NOT a prime number");
  for (c = 2; c <= 100; c++) {
    if (c == 2 || c == 3) {
      printf("%d is a prime number\n", c);
    } else {
      factors = 0;
      checkifprime(c);
      fputc('\n',stdout);
      // you had a typo here "=" instead of "=="
      if (factors == 0) {
        printf("%d is a prime number\n", c);
      } else {
        printf("%d is NOT a prime number\n", c);
      }
    }
  }
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int checkifprime(int num)
{
  int i;
  if (num > 0 && num < 2147483640) {
    for (i = num - 1; i > 1; i--)
    {
      if (num % i == 0) {
        factors = factors + 1;
        printf(" %d", i);
      }
    }
  }
//program finished
  return 0;
}
```

It is still not ideal but at least it works and you can build on it.

Comment: Thank you very much... These damn typos...

Comment: Nope. That typo wasn't the only problem.. still need answers.. :(

Comment: The code I posted runs and works as intended: it prints if it is a prime of not. If you still have problems you have to ask explicitely with a description of your problem.

Comment: I'm not complaining, I am very grateful for your help. I was just saying that even though you've thoughtfully provided me with an answer, I still haven't figured out why exactly my program didn't work.

Comment: @OmarQazi than it *is* my fault because I haven't explained it well enough. I think the remaining problem is the `printf("\n%d is a prime number", &c);` which must be `printf("\n%d is a prime number", c);` to work (needs to be changed in both places). Please check.

Comment: Thanks, that must've been the problem. I deleted the entire code I wrote and rewrote it in a different manner. It worked like a charm... Thanks again. :)